# IP address not redirecting when using /subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having an issue properly redirecting the public IP of my server to the domain name. Here is the issue:

*(Heads up: It's WP related but I still think stackoverflow might be the right forum to ask)*

I used Bitnami to deploy WordPress onto a AWS Lightsail instance. After following all guides I changed the following lines in wp-config.php from

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

to

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com');
```

To be honest, from my understanding and also experience this should do the trip. However, while my site get's properly redirected when just typing in the IP address it doesn't when using a full permalink to a page, e.g. 0.000.000.00/page. Instead, the page shows up and creates duplicate content.

I've been trying to find a solution for hours now. I also tried adding the following to my .htaccess with no luck.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^00\.00\.000\.000
RewriteRule (.*)  http://example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help, suggestion or hint would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the default WordPress `.htaccess` content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` appear to be working, which suggests the issue is only with permalinks. The above `.htaccess` should help. You can always combine your `.htaccess` code with the above if required.

Comment: Thanks Niraj, I have tried this and yet I'm still facing the same issue. :(

Comment: Hi Niraj, I've been trying around and finally managed to redirect IP/subfolder, however, now I'm facing the issue that it always redirects to the homepage. I started a new threat here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235863/how-to-properly-redirect-ip-address-followed-by-subfolder-to-matching-permalink - Sorry, don't want to start a million threads about this issue but also didn't want to change the initial problem in this one.